# Find invisible text in iText

Tags: java, itext

I am creating a PDF document of multiple pages using iText. I am adding some unique text on one of the pages in the middle of this document but making it invisible as-

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("invisible text here");
chunk.setTextRenderMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_INVISIBLE, 0f, null);
com.lowagie.text.Document iTextDoc.add(new Paragraph(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED, chunk));
```

The reason for adding this invisible text is to identify this particular page at the time of `onEndPage()`. But it is failing.
To achieve in the `onEndPage()`, I have the following code -

```
boolean b = (pdfWriter.getDirectContent().toString()).contains("invisible text here");
```

I get the value of `b` as `false`.
If I compare any other text on that page(which is visible) results `b` as `true`.
I tried to manually search the invisible text in the PDF reader and it finds the text.
What could I modify to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never a good idea to assume you can recognize text in the content without elaborate parsing. The text may be split into multiple segments, encoding might not be platform's default character encoding, etc... Thus don't try something like

```
boolean b = (pdfWriter.getDirectContent().toString()).contains("invisible text here");
```

You can achieve your goal

> The reason for adding this invisible text is to identify this particular page at the time of onEndPage().

much more easily. Simply add a member to your `PdfPageEvent` implementation, i.e. the class with your `onEndPage()` method, and set it where you used to add the invisible page content to the text you used to add to the page.

Now you can test that member variable directly in your `onEndPage().` Don't forget to reset the variable afterwards, preferably in `onEndPage()` itself!

Comment: Perfect. Have done exactly as you have suggested. Infact while debugging, I could even see all the members of my class implementation but just dint realize to add a member and then check it later as you have suggested. Thank you.